# What is the difference between 「欸」 and 「诶」?

Tags: difference

The first time I notice the word 欸 is in a game (Genshin Impact) with 欸嘿. Then I find another word 诶, which is not that so common vs 欸. So what is the difference between them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

欸 and 诶 are both modal word and only used to express some meaningless sound in a dialogue. They sound same, they have no meaning, and usually we don't talk about their difference.

Answer (score 0):

欸 is old Chinese and it is replaced and now more commonly written as the character 唉. It’s colloquially used in many places in different domains - be it dialogues of old Chinese drama or chinese games or even characters in it. Fun fact: Chinese language has more than 70,000 characters out of which only 20,000-30,000 is taught and used in everyday Chinese (Spoken and written) language. AFAIK, these are just exclamation sounds and do not necessarily have any meanings. Some other examples are 嗯, 哇 and so on.

Comment: No, you are wrong. 唉 stands for sigh, for example, 「唉，我又考砸了」. But 欸 is used as 「欸，你怎么在这」「好欸」.

Answer (score 0):

Both words are the same type - "interjection/exclamation; they share the same pronunciations ([ēi],[éi],[ěi],[èi]) with similar uses but the exceptions below:

- [欸](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%AC%B8)[ǎi] - 欸乃 is an Onomatopoeia, that phonetically imitates the sound of skulling the boat with a long oar (指摇橹声).
- [诶](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%AF%B6)[xī] - 1. used when expressing negative feelings about an odious event/person. 2. used with a forced smile.